# How to share message from reactjs app on Snapchat web

Tags: reactjs, snapchat

I was trying to share message from my **reactjs** app to **Snapchat Web**, but did not succeed. For exp: I have a button **Share On Snapchat**, once clicked, it should open Snapchat web and allow me to select any of my contacts and send message like "Hello world", this message must be from reactjs app.

I have tried  - but still could not succeed.

I will be so much thankful for any help you could do.

Here is what i have tried

```
    <button
          className="snapchat-share-button"
          data-share-url={process.env.REACT_APP_WEBSITE_URL}
          onClick={handleSnapchatShare}
        >
          Snapchat
        </button>
```

And handler is

```
  const handleSnapchatShare=()=>{
    const message = 'Hello, this is a message shared from my app!';
    const deepLink = `https://web.snapchat.com/1e543384-8ee4-5283-99e7-dd07628700a2?attachmentUrl=${encodeURIComponent("https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/10/3.jpg")}&caption=${encodeURIComponent(message)}`;
    window.location.href = deepLink;

  }
```

REACT_APP_WEBSITE_URL is public URL and is valid.
It opens Snapchat web, but it always asks to download snapchat app - How can i download snapchat for desktop because it shows following Interface with login option for desktop

[image]

It just get's me to snapchat web and i have nothing to share - no message there.